# Bulk replace 2 lines of code inside an XML template using notepad++

Tags: xml, regex, notepad++

I have a huge XML file, and I need to replace these 2 lines:

```
<blockquote>
<p style="text-align: justify;">
```

by:

```
<blockquote>
```

In other terms, I need to remove the:

```
<p style="text-align: justify;">
```

from the quote. I tried the search/replace in notepad++ but it takes only one line into account. Also, is there a way to remove the closing tag:

```
</p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to set the search mode to Regular expression and search and replace the following string

```
<blockquote>\r\n<p style="text-align: justify;">
```

for

```
<blockquote>
```

Now, assuming your closing `</p>` tags always follow some text such that:

```
<blockquote>
<p style="text-align: justify;">Some text</p>
```

You can then search for

```
<blockquote>\r\n<p style="text-align: justify;">(.*)</p>
```

and replace with

```
<blockquote>\1
```

which will remove your `<p>` tags completely.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! And how to remove the closing tag </p> inside the blockquote?

Comment: I suspect that the closing <p> tag will be a lot more awkward - the browser may need to know how to interpret DOM structure. If you can assume there will be no <p> inside of another <p>, you might be able to just "grab the next </p>" and remove, but not sure how to and not sure if you can assume that.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
<blockquote>\r\n<p style="text-align: justify;">
```

As search string and tick the `Advanced (\n, \r, \t, \0, \x...) box in the "Search mode" box in Notepad++. This will make Notepad recognize the linebreak correctly.